# css navigation menu

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make a navigation menu without using any image by CSS. But I don't know how to have those triangular border line at the end of each menu items. Following image would make my idea more clear:[image]

any good turorial of CSS or JQuery would be a GREAT help!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to draw the above image on a page purely in css without using any image files? If so, why?

Comment: and what about base64 encoding the images and including that in the CSS?

Answer (score 2):

This website is an excellent example of various shapes you can create via CSS. Hope this helps!

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

For example you can create a sort of "Chevron" with the following CSS

```
#chevron {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
}

#chevron:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
}
#chevron:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
}​
```

You can of course rotate the div as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a hard time making those polygons without images. Check out [CSS Sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/). I think it would suit your needs perfectly to create reposition background images to achieve the display effects you're looking for.